# Render List<Canvas> as list items (or itemscontrol)

Tags: silverlight, canvas, binding

I've effectively got a List or a List, XAML that represents the canvas elements... as a return from some stuff I have no control of.

I've been moderately successful rendering via stackpanel.children.add etc, however want to start having the list of canvas within a virtualizing panel or list.

I've set itemssource and datacontext on the `<ItemsControl>` and set the `<DataTemplate>` as such

```
<DataTemplate>
   <ContentControl content="{Binding Path=CanvasBody}"/> 
</DataTemplate>
```

This effectively turns entire silverlight body white/blank. I dont really care how I ultimately get to the desired result which is a list of the rendered canvas's... preferably virtualized for speed.

Its a retarded problem, and not ideal as far as how silverlight apps are built, I know...

I'd really appreciate any pointers. THANKS!

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some parts. I'd suggest you revise it to fill in the blanks above.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to display a list of elements you bind the items control itemssource property to the list and then set a datatemplate for it which displays the desired properties of the list item type. You dont need to set content control. Beyond that I cant see what exactly you are asking.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExampleProperty1}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

codebehind file:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public String ExampleProperty1
    {
        get
        {
            return "TEST";
        }
    }
}

public List<ExampleClass> List {get;} // note that this must be a public PROPERTY,    
                                      // not a field!
```